# How do I find out how long a command has been running for using time command?

Tags: linux, command-line, mysqldump

I have a long `mysqldump` thats been running for over 2 days now (many 100s of GBs of data being archived). I started the command with `time` so that I could see how long it took when it finished.

Is there a signal that I can send to `time` to get it to print the amount of time elapsed so far since the command was run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you started it with `time mysqldump ...`, which most likely uses the shell built-in `time`, not `/usr/bin/time` or `/bin/time`. I don't think there's a possibility to make it print the time.

However, you can `cd /proc/$(pgrep mysqldump)` and check some statistics there. If all you want to know is how long it is since you started it, you can just run

```
ps faxo pid,cls,stat,pri,euser,pcpu,etime,rss:8,args
```

which will show the elapsed time in the 7th column as "days-hours:minutes:seconds".

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ps aux | grep mysqld` the tenth column should show you the running time of the process.

The second column shows the process id (say XYZ), and you can check that in realtime by running `top -pid XYZ`.